# Store response from the random text/color generator, compare them and store in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, random, compare

I am doing a javascript webpage to demonstrate stroop effect, which is to show that it takes longer for a person to choose the right color if the color of the word does not match with its semantic meaning. For example, click "blue" button if the word RED in blue color.

However, since the color and the word are randomly generated, I dont know how to store them into a new array and compare them.

At the end of the experiment, I want to have an alert. If the question is "RED in blue color", then it will show "DIFF", if the question is "RED in red color", then it will show "SAME" for the 10 questions. Thanks for help! I have the code as below

```
<html>

<head>


<title> random text </title>

<script type="text/javascript"> 



//array 

var quotations = new Array();

quotations[0]= "red";
quotations[1]= "yellow";
quotations[2]= "green";
quotations[3]= "blue";

var colours = new Array();

colours[0] = "red";
colours[1] = "yellow";
colours[2] = "green";
colours[3] = "blue";

//Randomize coloured text 9 times and on tenth time, display alert


var NumberAttempts = 0;

var choice;

var score =0;

function display()
{

 if ( NumberAttempts < 10) 

 { 

  var a = Math.floor(Math.random()*quotations.length)document.getElementById ("txtbox").value=quotations[a];


  choice = Math.floor(Math.random()*colours.length);document.getElementById    ("txtbox").style.color=colours[choice];


  NumberAttempts++;


 }

  else

 {

  alert ("You are done! The number of correct attempts is " + score + ".");

 }
}

function compare(c1)
{
 if (colours[choice]==c1)
  {
   score++;    
  }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h1><center>Using Computer Science to Demonstrate the Stroop Effect</center></h1>
<div>
<ul>
<li><a href="http://introduction.html" target="_blank"> Introduction </a></li>
<li><a href="http://instructions.html" target="_blank"> Instructions </a></li>
</ul>

<textarea id="txtbox" style="width:600px;"></textarea><br />

<button onClick='compare("red");display()'><font color="red">Red </font></button>

<button onClick='compare("yellow");display()'><font color="yellow">Yellow</font></button>

<button onClick='compare("green");display()'><font color="green">Green</font></button>

<button onClick='compare("blue");display()'><font color="blue">Blue</font></button>



</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I am not clear with the result of your experiment. What should it give the result after 10 attempts

Comment: @polin It should show something like this:"You are done! the number of correct attempts is 5. Qn1: SAME-blue/BLUE; Qn2: DIFF-blue/RED..."

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>

<head>


<title> random text </title>

<script type="text/javascript"> 

window.onload=display;

//array 

var quotations = new Array();

quotations[0]= "red";
quotations[1]= "yellow";
quotations[2]= "green";
quotations[3]= "blue";

var colours = new Array();

colours[0] = "red";
colours[1] = "yellow";
colours[2] = "green";
colours[3] = "blue";

//Randomize coloured text 9 times and on tenth time, display alert

var arr=new Array(10,1);
x=0;
y=0;
var NumberAttempts = 0;

var choice;

var score =0;

function display()
{

 if ( NumberAttempts < 10) 

 { 

  var a = Math.floor(Math.random()*quotations.length);
  document.getElementById("txtbox").value=quotations[a];


  choice = Math.floor(Math.random()*colours.length);
  document.getElementById("txtbox").style.color=colours[choice];
    arr[x,0]=colours[choice];
    arr[x,1]=quotations[a];
    x=x+1;
    console.log(arr);

  NumberAttempts++;


 }

  else

 {

  alert ("You are done! The number of correct attempts is " + score + ".");


 }
}

function compare(c1)
{
 if (colours[choice]==c1)
  {
   score++;

  }

}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h1><center>Using Computer Science to Demonstrate the Stroop Effect</center></h1>
<div>
<ul>
<li><a href="http://introduction.html" target="_blank"> Introduction </a></li>
<li><a href="http://instructions.html" target="_blank"> Instructions </a></li>
</ul>

<textarea id="txtbox" style="width:600px;"></textarea><br />

<button onClick="compare(this.id);display()" id="red"><font color="red">Red </font></button>

<button onClick="compare(this.id);display()" id="yellow"><font color="yellow">Yellow</font></button>

<button onClick="compare(this.id);display()" id="green"><font color="green">Green</font></button>

<button onClick="compare(this.id);display()" id="blue"><font color="blue">Blue</font></button>



</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Just another question. I want to show the color and the text of the word displaying instead of the color and what the user choose. I tried to change arr[x,0]=quotations[a]; arr[x,1]=colours[choice]; but it is not working and says a is not defined?

Comment: I've just edited my code and I think it'll show what you want

Comment: Thank you! is there any possibility that I can show the result of the console.log at the end of the 10th attempt?

Comment: yes I've written "console.log(arr)" part in a if part.you write it in its else part